# Laravel file upload redirects user to login page

Tags: laravel, authentication, upload

I'm having an issue with file upload in Laravel. I have a file upload feature, but every time user uploads a file, user gets automatically redirected to login page. Any suggestions?

Comment: is the user authorized to upload a file?

Comment: Yes, the user is authenticated to upload the file and folder structure has 777 permissions as well. It is working fine on 'localhost'.

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: 1. Here's the controller code:
public function uploadfile($id) {
 $file = $_FILES['files'];

 $fileExtension = explode(".", $file["name"]);
 $fileuploadpath = date("Y") . "/" . date("m") . "/" . date("d") . "/";
 if(!file_exists("uploads/" . $fileuploadpath))
  mkdir("uploads/" . $fileuploadpath, 0777, true);

 if(move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], 'uploads/' . $fileuploadpath.$id)) {
  echo $fileuploadpath;
 } else {
  echo json_encode(['html' => 'Unable to move file. Is folder writable?']);    
 }
}

Comment: Here's the php code (part 1)

myfile.blade.php

$(".submitbutton").click(function() {
 var textdata = $("#textData").val();
 var files = $("#orgz_file_name").get(0).files[0];
 var filename = '';
 var fileuploadpath = '';
 var x = document.getElementById("orgz_file_name");

 if ('files' in x) {
  if (x.files.length == 0) {
  }
  else
  {
   if(files.size < 2097152) {
    filename = files.name;
    var file = files;
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append('fileselected', file);

Comment: php code (part 2)

$.ajax({
     url : "/upload/" + filename,
     type: "POST",
     cache: false,
     async: false,
     contentType: false,
     processData: false,
     data : form,
     success: function(response){
      // reponse file upload path
      if(response != '' || response != null) {
       fileuploadpath = response;
      }
      else {
       alert('File type not allowed.');
      }
     }
    });
   } else {
    alert('File size should be less than 2 MB.');
   }
  }

Comment: php code (part 3):

$formData = {
   textdata: textdata
   filepath: fileuploadpath,
   filename: filename
  }

  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/datasave",
   data: $formData,
   async: false,
   cache: true,
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (data) {
    // Code for UI update etc.
   }
  });
 }
});

Comment: Sorry - let me know if there's a more elegant way to share the code